# Azure BlobStorage: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

When I try to upload blobs to my azure storage account I get the following error response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Error>
    <Code>OutOfRangeInput</Code>
    <Message>One of the request inputs is out of range. 
           RequestId:--------------------------
           Time:2017-10-29T07:13:37.4218874Z
    </Message>
  </Error>
```

I am uploading multiple blobs of which some are uploaded successfully while others are not. The ones that throw the error have large blob-names (about 100 characters) so assume it may be due to blob-names size. But according to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2014/06/12/azure-storage-naming-rules/ the maximum blob-names can be 1024 and my blob-names are way less than that limit.

An example blob-name would be "65/36/aluminium_03_group67_product_02pCube1_product_02group2_product_02Flow000_Albedo.png"

**Edit Code to upload the blob.**

The code to upload is in Javascript. I am breaking the file into multiple chunks and uploading. Here is the function responsible for uploading files

```
function AzureFileUpload(file, uploadUrl, successCallback, progressCallback, errorCallback){
    this.file = file;
    this.uploadUrl = uploadUrl;
    this.successCallback = successCallback;
    this.progressCallback = progressCallback;
    this.errorCallback = errorCallback;
    this.reader = new FileReader();
    this.maxBlockSize = 256 * 1024;
    this.blockIds = [];
    this.totalBytesRemaining = this.file.size;
    this.currentFilePointer = 0;
    this.bytesUploaded = 0;
    this.uploadFlag = true;
    var self = this;
    this.reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
            var uri = self.uploadUrl + '&comp=block&blockid=' + self.blockIds[self.blockIds.length - 1];
            var requestData = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);
            self.ReadBlock();
            if(self.uploadFlag){
                self.UploadBlock(requestData, uri);
            }
        }
    };
    this.ReadBlock();
}

AzureFileUpload.prototype.UploadBlock = function(requestData, blockUrl){
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: blockUrl,
        type: "PUT",
        data: requestData,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-cache-control', "public, max-age=864000");
        },
        success: function(data, status) {
            self.UpdateProgress(requestData.length);
            self.bytesUploaded += requestData.length;
            if (parseFloat(self.bytesUploaded) == parseFloat(self.file.size)) {
                self.CommitBlocks();
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            // console.log(desc);
            // console.log(err);
            self.Error("Unexpected error occured while uploading model. Plaese try after some time");
        }
    });
};

AzureFileUpload.prototype.pad = function(number, length){
    var str = '' + number;
    while (str.length < length) {
        str = '0' + str;
    }
    return str;
};

AzureFileUpload.prototype.ReadBlock = function(){
    if (this.totalBytesRemaining > 0) {
        var fileContent = this.file.slice(this.currentFilePointer, this.currentFilePointer + this.maxBlockSize);
        var blockId = "block-" + this.file.name + "-" + this.pad(this.blockIds.length, 6);
        this.blockIds.push(btoa(blockId));
        this.reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileContent);
        this.currentFilePointer += this.maxBlockSize;
        this.totalBytesRemaining -= this.maxBlockSize;
        if (this.totalBytesRemaining < this.maxBlockSize) {
            this.maxBlockSize = this.totalBytesRemaining;
        }
    }
};

AzureFileUpload.prototype.UpdateProgress = function(bytesUploaded){
    console.log("Progress",bytesUploaded);
    if(this.progressCallback){
        this.progressCallback(bytesUploaded);
    }
};

AzureFileUpload.prototype.CommitBlocks = function(){
    var self = this;
    var uri = this.uploadUrl + '&comp=blocklist';
    var request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><BlockList>';
    for (var i = 0; i < this.blockIds.length; i++) {
        request += '<Latest>' + this.blockIds[i] + '</Latest>';
    }
    request += '</BlockList>';
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: "PUT",
        data: request,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-content-type', self.file.type);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-cache-control', "public, max-age=864000");
        },
        success: function(data, status) {
            console.log("Block Commited", data);
            if(self.successCallback){
                self.successCallback();
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            self.Error("Unexpected error occured while uploading model. Plaese try after some time");
        }
    });
};

AzureFileUpload.prototype.Error = function(msg){
    this.CancelUpload();
    if(this.errorCallback){
        this.errorCallback(msg);
    }
};

AzureFileUpload.prototype.CancelUpload = function(){
    this.uploadFlag = false;
};
```

Comment: Please share the code for uploading the blobs.

Comment: @GauravMantri edited the question to include the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the following line of code:

```
var blockId = "block-" + this.file.name + "-" + this.pad(this.blockIds.length, 6);
```

Essentially the max length of a block id can be 64 bytes (Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block - see URI parameters section). Because you're including file name in block id computation and your file name is large, you're exceeding this limitation.

Please try with the following line of code and you should not get this error:

```
var blockId = "block-" + this.pad(this.blockIds.length, 6);
```

Please note that block ids are scoped to a blob so it is not really necessary for you to include the blob name to make the block ids unique to a blob.

Answer (score 3):

If your using a connection string this could also be an issue, double check it (and the casing) as container names etc are case sensitive. You can read more on naming rules here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata?redirectedfrom=MSDN